# Имитация создания дампа памяти из BSoD для MS-DOS

Tags: c, borland

Я от нечего делать пишу программу, которая имитирует Синий Экран Смерти на MS-DOS (не DosBox). Компилятор - Borland C++ 3.1 (?) Цвет сделал с помощью присваивания значения 01437 в B8000000UL. Теперь реализую создание дампа памяти. Тут возникла проблема. Как известно, при создании реального дампа на третьей-четвёртой (точно не помню) строчке снизу ведётся счётчик от 1 до 100, потом на второй-третьей строчке появляется "Physical dump of memory complete.". Загвоздка в том, что текст у меня так вошёл в границы экрана, что при печати "Dumping physical memory to disk: `<число>`" на самой нижней строчке сверху появляется лишняя строка, а при вставлении перед "Dumping..." перевода строки не остаётся места для "Physical...". Максимум, что получилось - печатать "Dumping...: 1" на строчке выше. Вопрос: как выводить счётчик не на самой нижней строке, а на второй-третьей строке снизу?

Comment: вы определяете границу экрана, печатаете пустые строки или вычисляете высоту экрана? Функцию GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) использовать пробовали?